# Prove that square matrix $A$ is invertible iff there exists basis $u,v$ such that $A=M(I,u\to v)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix any $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, let $I: V \to V$ be its identity operator. For any $n \times n$ matrix $A$. Prove that $A$ is invertible if and only if there exists a basis $u$ and $v$ of $V$, such that $A$ is the matrix representation of $I$ against basis $u$ (basis in the domain) and $v$ (basis in the codomain).

Attempt:

$(=>)$ my attempt is to first fix any random basis $v$ and define $u$ by $u_i=A_{i1}v_1+A_{i2}v_2+\dots$. Then I need to show that $u_i$ is actually a basis. We can represent this in matrix form $u^T=v^TA$. And we want to show $u^T w=v^TAw=0 \implies w=0$ for independence. Since $v$ is independent, we have $Aw=0$ and thus $w=0$ by invertibility of $A$. Since $u$ is of right length, this should prove $u$ is a basis and $A=M(I,u\to v)$ by construction.

$(<=)$ Simply write $ B=M(I,v \to u)$. Then $AB=I, BA=I$ follows.

Question

Are there any cleaner, more intuitive way to see $(=>)$ direction? Thank you!

Comment: This question is important for me to understand that similar matrices are matrix representation of the same linear operator against different basis. So any insights related to this are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a fundamentally more elegant approach here. One thing you can do to clean it up a bit is to use the standard basis for your $v_i$s, rather than an arbitrary basis. Then $Av_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$, which you still need to show is a basis. This, in turn, might shorten your proof, as you may already have access to results showing that, if $A$ is invertible, then its columns form a basis.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $\textsf V$ is a vector space *over a field* $F$.

$\Rightarrow )$ If $A$ is invertible, then the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, so, choose the basis $u$ as the set formed by the columns of $A$, that is
$$u=\{Ae_1,Ae_2,\dots,Ae_n\}$$
and choose $v$ as the standard basis of $\textsf{F}^n$
$$v=\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n\}$$
It follows that $[\textsf{I}_\textsf V]_u^v =A$.